grub config for newly installed grub
I have installed grub from source code compile with 2.12 latest. For this install was on plain boot and later I copied all stuff to encrypted boot. It works fine for encrypted boot except it starts with plain boot grub.cfg file. Later I execute grub.cfg of encrypted boot. Actually location is /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu1/ and there is I kept signed grub image of 2.12. Problem is this should boot grubx64-signed.efi with grub.cfg in same directory. However, it boots uuid of plain boot grub.cfg and later I interrupt it and start config file of encrypted boot. Does grub-install configure somewhere which grub.cfg file it has to pick and which will that be by default? My ubuntu is 22.04

All official and many unofficial flavors of Ubuntu only use /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to boot. I rename ever install, so unique in grub menu, and it even adds a unique UEFI entry on grub install. But something is hard coded in Ubuntu's UEFI boot entry to always use /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. I have manually edited the three line grub.cfg to change UUID of default boot, but now just use grub of a new install to boot into my main working install & reinstall grub which updates /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg entry.

See ./util/grub-install.c:   efi_distributor = bootloader_id; But somewhere else it reverts to "ubuntu" I used this with grub 2.02 then gave up.  find . -type f -print | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs grep -i "efi_distributor" & find . -type f -print | sed 's/ /\ /g' | xargs grep -i "bootloader_id"
